# How to center UILabel text horizontally (Up/Down) in frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is subclassed from a [simple control.](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel) The problem that I'm having is that the text in the label is being formatted into the very top left corner of its frame. Normally UILabel text will be centered horizontally in the frame, not all the way against the top.

I am needing to have the text centered horizontally(up/down) in my UILabel. What can I do to make that happen?

I have code posted below that shows what I'm doing and the UILabel is an outlet property for an object on my storyboard view controller. I have constraints set on this label so that it fits in its superview dynamically.

```
- (void)setTitleForCell:(NSString *)title
{
    [self.titleLabel setText:title];

    UIColor *titleColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *titleParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [titleParagraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [titleParagraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSDictionary *titleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:titleColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:13.0f], NSFontAttributeName, titleParagraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
    [self.titleLabel setAttributes:titleAttributes];

    NSDictionary *handleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor lightGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:13.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    NSDictionary *hashtagAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor lightGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:13.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];

    [self.titleLabel setAttributes:handleAttributes hotWord:STTweetHandle];
    [self.titleLabel setAttributes:hashtagAttributes hotWord:STTweetHashtag];

    [self.titleLabel setDetectionBlock:^(STTweetHotWord hotWord, NSString *string, NSString *protocol, NSRange range) {
        NSArray *hotWords = @[@"Handle", @"Hashtag", @"Link"];

        if (hotWord == STTweetHandle) {

        }
    }];
}
```

I have also set the background of the frame to a color so that I could see how it's setup, but it's just like I thought, the text is aligned to the top as much as it possibly could be. There is still plenty of space below the text.

Comment: Check that you don't have any newlines at the end of your text.

Comment: You mean centered vertically (up/down). Horizontally is left/right.

Comment: What constraints you have on that label? I don't think UILabel would center its content vertically.

Comment: @sha My UILabel is set into a UITableViewCell and each of its edges touch the bounds of that cell. So leading, trailing, top, and bottom spaces are all to superview. Nothing fishy with the constraints.

Comment: @Jonathan: Exactly. See my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change your constraints for the label in way that its height is not fixed (when you specify 0 from top, 0 from bottom - height is fixed to the height of the cell), and that it centered vertically in container.

As a side note: when troubleshooting layout issues I found extremely useful to set temporary background colors to various bright colors (`cell` to green, `title` to blue for example) so it's clear what frame each view is occupying.